# Redis: is it possible to store an array, but every item has an independent exp. date?

Tags: redis

Here is a problem - I want to store an array of strings, add new values to the array and retrieve all the items that has not been expired yet.

```
values = [
  "key1" => ttl,
  "key2" => ttl,
]
```

The other way is to store it with regulat GET/SET methods, but in this case I won't be able to get all the values in one request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis only supports the expiration of keys, not values within keys. This includes members of Sets, fields in Hashes, and, in your case, elements in a List.